# Solving an equation with matrices, vectors and logarithm

Tags: matrices, logarithms, vectors

I have to solve an equation that involves a matrix, two vectors and logarithm inbetween.
$$\log(s_{2}) = M  \log(s_{1})$$
$M$ is a $n\times n$ matrix, $s_{1}$ and $s_{2}$ are two $n \times 1$ vectors. I want an expressions linking s2 to s1 without a log between them, so I wanted to use the $\exp()$ but as the right side of the equation is a product of matrix and vector I am not sure whether this is allowed or not (I highly doubt it is) , and what would be the resulting relation.

Is it possible ?

Comment: Is $\log$ defined to be element-wise?

Comment: Yes, is there any other way to define it for vectors ? I don't know.

Comment: Well, then you can just as easily define the $\exp$ function on vectors...

Comment: I guess, but what I need is to have a simple relation in which both $s_{1}$ and $s_{2}$ and not inside a log and an exp, something like a linear relation. In this case, if I use $exp$ on both sides, will I be able to simplify the right side ?

Comment: Well, the elements of $s_1$ and those of $s_2$ aren't connected in a linear equation, so you won't get a linear eqation no matter what you do...

Comment: My objective was to get something like $c_{2}=Ac_{1}$ with a new matrix A, $c_{2}=c_{1}+b$ or a combination of these. I was almost convinced it was not possible, but I wanted to be sure before . Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Your equation is really a set of equations $$\begin{bmatrix}\log((s_2)_1)\\\log((s_2)_2)\\\vdots\\\log((s_2)_n)\end{bmatrix}=M\cdot \begin{bmatrix}\log((s_1)_1)\\\log((s_1)_2\\\vdots\\\log((s_1)_n\end{bmatrix}$$

So, if you introduce a new variable $x_i = \log((s_2)_i)$ and $y_i=\log((s_1)_i)$, you can solve the matrix equation $$x = M\cdot y$$ (where $x=[x_1,x_2\dots, x_n]^T$, of course).

Then, once you have $x$, you have $x_i$ for each $i$ and you can calculate $(s_2)_i=e^{x_i}$